# Is "is this old information still true?" an appropriate comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, updating-questions

If I read a question from a couple years ago, especially when it explicitly references version information and is based on testing that is hard or time consuming to reproduce like this one: [When to use views in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/16372/53784), I wonder whether the information is still accurate. If all I am looking for is a "yes" or "no" to that question what is the most appropriate way to solicit that?

The question isn't necessarily irrelevant because it refers to old information; it only *might* be, which is why I'm not sure asking a new question would be advisable. (I realize that there is plenty of discussion on the former scenario. [e. 1 g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179469/165320), [e. 2 g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86864/165320)) But I'm also not sure a comment would serve my purpose because what am really doing is asking a substantive metaquestion.

. . . and if my question is a dupe I might just be too far down the meta rabbit hole to ever recover.

**Update:** This is also relevant to avoiding situations like [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507795/can-i-use-a-database-view-as-a-model-in-django#comment35628801_508013).

Answer (score 3):

In most situations, just asking "Is this information still accurate?" is not a terribly useful comment, if there is no specific reason to expect that the answer is wrong (other than age).  Such a comment isn't prohibited, but it's not very constructive and it is closer to "noise" than to "signal".  If everyone posted such comments every time they ran across a question that was a year or two old, we'd be inundated in useless comments and clutter.

However, if you have a specific reason to doubt the answer, a comment that asks "Is this information still accurate?  I noticed that version 2.x now supports the Blazzle interface which looks more appropriate" (or whatever the reason is) would be more appropriate.  Make sure to explain in the comment the specific reason that makes you aren't sure whether the answer is still accurate today.  That shifts the comment from noise to signal.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are intended to be meta questions in the first place.  They're also not held to the same level of quality that an answer is.  If you have something constructive to ask or say, and it has something to do with the post that you want to comment on, then feel free to comment.

Asking if the old information is still true is perfectly fine.  Just don't necessarily expect to get an answer.  The author of the answer might not still be around to get your notification, and you comment will not bump the question.

Also know that sometimes individual stack exchanges can have their own customs in regards to commenting, so if you're curious about a specific site, then ask on the site-specific meta.

Comment: No expecting to get an answer would seem to be an implicit argument in favor of asking it as a new question under the assumption that the answers will be different because things have changed. But it is just as likely that it doesn't get answered because, well. . . it's just a comment.